# AngularJs Scope, variable value get changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am totally new to AngularJs, i have taken tutorials, I had been stuck from last 5 hours on following problem,

I am using twitterbootstrap and by modal i meant [bootstrap modal](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

It show me the modal once when i click on slot and save is also worked 1st time but second time, it call the addingBooking method initialize the currentBooking object, but not show the modal.

this is my view in haml, simple showing bootstrap modal and its working fine.

```
#scheduler{ :'ng-controller' => 'SchedulerCtrl', :scheduler => true, :data =>{:interval =>  @interval, :restaurant_id => @restaurant_id}  }

  #booking-editor.modal.hide.fade{ :'aria-hidden' => true, :'aria-labelledby' => "bookingEditorLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1", :'booking-editor' => 'currentBooking', :'ng-controller' => 'BookingEditorCtrl' }
    .modal-body
      %input{ :type => "text", :'ng-model' => "currentBooking.name" }
    .modal-footer
      %button.btn{ :'aria-hidden' => true, :'data-dismiss' => "modal" } Close
      %button.btn.btn-primary{ :'ng-click' => 'saveBooking(currentBooking)' } Save Booking
```

**Scheduler Controller**;

```
  $scope.addBooking = (slot) ->
    $scope.currentBooking = { name: "John Doe", new: true }
```

**BookingEditorCntl**

```
@BookingEditorCtrl = ['$scope', '$resource', ($scope, $resource) ->
  $scope.saveBooking = (booking) ->
    $scope.currentBooking = null
]
```

**Directive part for DOM manipulation**

```
  .directive 'bookingEditor', ->
    restrict: 'A'
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) ->
      scope.$watch attrs.bookingEditor, ->
        if scope[attrs.bookingEditor]
          $(element).modal(keyboard: true)
          $(element).modal('show')
        else
          $(element).modal('hide')
```

Any suggestions or thoughts please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what modal plugin you are using, so it is a little hard to help. However, from your example, it looks like you are calling `$(element).modal(keyboard: true)` multiple times. This could explain why you're getting an error. If this is the case, something like the following could help:

**In `BookingEditorCtrl`:**

```
$scope.modalInitialized = false;
```

**In `bookingEditor` directive:**

```
if(scope.modalInitialized === false)
    $(element).modal(keyboard: true)
$(element).modal('show')
```

Comment: m using bootstrap, and by modal i meant bootstrap modal, http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Plus will u please elaborate what you exactly meant by m call keyboard: true multiple timeS ?